# Planes overlapped by cube in Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm having a few planes with a simple texture on them, and a cube underneath. The issue is that planes seem to get overlapped by the cube when they are actually still in front of it.

Example can be seen here :
http://denishacquin.be/canvas3d/canvas_particles_floor.html

(Use mouse to rotate camera)

I'm sure this must be pretty simple but I'm new to three.js and I've spent hours looking for an answer.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Here, take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/about).  Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is an artifact of `CanvasRenderer`. The best you can do is tessellate your geometry. For example,

```
THREE.CubeGeometry( 100, 100, 100, 4, 1, 4 );
THREE.PlaneGeometry( 100, 100, 4, 4 );
```

The other alternative is to switch to `WebGLRenderer`.

three.js r.58

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, tesselating works, but it's too bad I have to increase the number of polygons just to fix an artifact. I will then switch to WebGLRenderer.